# Using the Angular interval timer function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a created a basic image slider which works well.

I am trying to make attempts to add the angular `$interval` service to my function in order for the slide to transition automatically.

Does any know how this can be achieved I am assuming this function only requires one or two lines of code. I've also [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ju6keOTWIdP8cCU3c11?p=preview)

```
// JOBS FLICKR FUNCTIONS 

$scope.jobNotification = 0;

var timer = $interval();

$scope.isActive = function (index) {
    return $scope.jobNotification === index;
};

$scope.showJobNotification = function (index) {
    $scope.jobNotification = index;
};
```

I've quite a few versions in bootstrap, however i trying to build something manually so i can understand what i am doing.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DxhkMkH9Rxe7lrKYDYF8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$interval takes in a function which will be called every X seconds.

```
var timeBetweenEachInterval = 5 * 1000; //5 seconds (or 5000 milliseconds)
var intervalPromise = $interval(function () { 
  //This function will be called every 5 seconds.
  index = index + 1;
  if (/*don't need interval anymore*/) {
    $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
  }
}, timeBetweenEachInterval);
```